# Sphinx4 - Is there a faster way to get full text from audio file?

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

From Sphinx4's demo in `TranscriberDemo.java`, hypothesis are gotten for each chunk of sound -- is there a faster way to get one final hypothesis at the end of processing?

```
    recognizer.startRecognition(stream);
    SpeechResult result;
    while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {

        System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n", result.getHypothesis());

        System.out.println("List of recognized words and their times:");
        for (WordResult r : result.getWords()) {
            System.out.println(r);
        }

        System.out.println("Best 3 hypothesis:");
        for (String s : result.getNbest(3))
            System.out.println(s);

    }
    recognizer.stopRecognition();
```

Comment: What do you mean _faster_?

Comment: Can it only be done iteratively, repeatedly getting the transcription of a short bit of speech, or is there a way to get the entire transcription in one step? Thank you.

Comment: There is, but you will have to hack the internals a little bit. It's much more easier to write a helper wrapper function around the code in the post.

Comment: What do you mean by "hack the internals"? Thanks.

Comment: I mean you will have to change the source code and/or configuration.